# Performance of Array.reduce

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I was trying out the Codility MaxCounter question:

You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

```
increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
max_counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
```

A non-empty zero-indexed array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

```
if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max_counter.
```

For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3  
A[1] = 4  
A[2] = 4  
A[3] = 6  
A[4] = 1  
A[5] = 4  
A[6] = 4
```

the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:

```
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)  
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)   
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0)  
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)  
(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)  
(3, 2, 2, 3, 2)  
(3, 2, 2, 4, 2)
```

The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

For example, given:

```
A[0] = 3  
A[1] = 4  
A[2] = 4  
A[3] = 6  
A[4] = 1  
A[5] = 4  
A[6] = 4
```

the function should return [3, 2, 2, 4, 2].

Assume that:

```
N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].
```

Complexity:

```
expected worst-case time complexity is O(N+M);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

Here is my solution, for which i used the reduce method. It scores 40% on performance. 
Can anyone see where the performance issue is here? 
I'm assuming perhaps it is the reduce speed itself thats the problem and that in order to increase this score i would need to convert this to for loops, but this just feels like a really ugly way to use modern javascript in this context.

Hopefully one of you will point out something non JS related about this solution that will not indicate that reduce is the issue and instead indicate that im an idiot (I will deal with the ramifications of this over a cold beer)

```
function maxCounter(N, A) {
    let maxCounter = 0
    const NArray = new Array(N).fill(0)

    const results = A.reduce((acc, current) => {
        if (current === N + 1) return new Array(N).fill(maxCounter)
        const out = acc.map((element, index) => {
            if (index + 1 === current){
                const newValue = element + 1
                if (newValue > maxCounter) maxCounter = newValue
                return newValue
            } else {
                return element
            }
        })
        return out
    }
    , NArray)
    return results
}

const results = maxCounter(5, [1,4,2,5,2,6,2])
console.log({results})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could introduce a `min` value, which is set if all values have to be set to the `max` value, but this does happen only if the value is incremented, then the `min` value is used for update or at the end to give all items at least the `min` value.

```js
function maxCounter(n, a) {
    var min = 0,
        max = 0,
        result = [],
        i;

    for (i of a) {
        if (--i === n) {
            min = max;
            continue;
        }
        if (!result[i] || result[i] < min) result[i] = min;
        if (++result[i] > max) max = result[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!result[i] || result[i] < min) result[i] = min;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(...maxCounter(5, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4]));
console.log(...maxCounter(5, [1, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 2]));
```

Comment: This seems to be evaluated as 100% performance on Codility (the best).

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your solution is O(*NM*), which exceeds the required complexity of O(*N* + *M*). The reason is that your solution builds a new array of length *N* for each of the *M* queries.

This isn't because you used `reduce`, but rather because you used `reduce` on an array of length *M* with a reduction operation which takes O(*N*) time. If your reduction operation took O(1) time instead, then you would be fine.

It is possible to achieve O(1) time per query by updating the counters array in-place; the hard part is answering the "set-all" query in O(1) time, i.e. without updating all *N* elements of the counter array. One solution is to record a kind of "timestamp" for the last time a counter was modified, and another "timestamp" for the last time "set-all" was done; this allows you to test if a counter's value is older than the most-recent "set-all" query, and get the correct counter value either way. Here's a class which answers both queries in O(1) using this technique:

```js
class Counters {
    constructor(n) {
        this.setallVal = 0;
        this.setallTimestamp = 0;
        this.maxCounter = 0;
        this.counts = new Array(n).fill(0);
        this.timestamps = new Array(n).fill(0);
    }
    getCounter(i) {
        if (this.timestamps[i] >= this.setallTimestamp) {
            return this.counts[i];
        } else {
            return this.setallVal;
        }
    }
    incCounter(i) {
        let c = this.getCounter(i) + 1;
        this.counts[i] = c;
        this.timestamps[i] = this.setallTimestamp;
        if (c > this.maxCounter) {
            this.maxCounter = c;
        }
    }
    setAllToMax() {
        this.setallVal = this.maxCounter;
        this.setallTimestamp++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@kaya3 Thanks!

I tried this too which gets 60% but i assume falls over with the same issue of setting the max across all elements

```
function solution(N, A) {
    let maxCounter = 0
    const NArray = new Array(N).fill(0)

    for (i=0; i<A.length; i++){
        if (A[i]>N){
            NArray.fill(maxCounter)
        } else {
            const currentVal = NArray[A[i] -1] + 1
            if  (currentVal > maxCounter) maxCounter = currentVal
            NArray[A[i] -1]  = currentVal
        }
    }
    return NArray
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is still O(*NM*) because of doing `Array.fill` up to O(*M*) times.